# submit button event using javascript

Tags: javascript, submit

Hi I've an html page with submit button. I want to call that submit button event froma a different page using javascript.

is it possible? Can some one give me any example. I'm searching for it from hours.

thank you,

Comment: What do you mean by "from a different page"? What's the relationship between the two pages?

Comment: i mean just i want to pass credential to my authentication page (third party) and want to get response by using javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use form.submit() method.

```
document.forms["myform"].submit();
```

Comment: form.submit() wil call current form right? but i want to call different page submit button

Comment: actually that page contains submit button. I want to call that submit button click event. Is it possible?

Comment: Or you require something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit

Comment: no actually that is a third party authentication page. Instead of going there and validating just i want to pass credentials from my page and trying to get respoinse. Hope you got it. And it is not a popup window just it is a site